# chart.js - Horizontal lines per bar

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to draw a chart with horizontal line per bar with 2 datasets(Actual,Target) using chart.js 2.9.2, like this:

[image]

but with no success... is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your target values into floating bars where individual bars are specified with the syntax `[min, max]`. Given an array of values named `targetData`, it can be converted with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows.

```
targetData.map(v => [v - 1, v + 1])
```

Further you need to define individual stacked `xAxis` for both datasets. In order to have the original target values displayed in the tooltips, a [`toolips.callback.label`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) function is also needed.

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet.

```js
const actualData = [100, 180, 120, 80, 140, 170, 160];
const targetData = [110, 150, 140, 100, 120, 110, 170];

new Chart("chart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["KPI 1", "KPI 2", "KPI 3", "KPI 4", "KPI 5", "KPI 6", "KPI 7"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Actual",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        data: actualData,
        xAxisID: "x-axis-actual"
      },
      {
        label: "Target",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 128, 1)',
        data: targetData.map(v => [v - 1, v + 1]),
        xAxisID: "x-axis-target"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          const v = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
          return Array.isArray(v) ? (v[1] + v[0]) / 2 : v;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          id: "x-axis-target",
          stacked: true
        },
        {
          display: false,
          offset: true,
          stacked: true,
          id: "x-axis-actual",
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="120"></canvas>
```