# ChartJS Adding Different Lines for each column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a bar chart in my react app, and I want to add different limit lines for each column. Does anybody know how to configure it?(For chartJS < 2.9.0) The following is an example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62717208/2358409

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chart.js - Horizontal lines per bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711919/chart-js-horizontal-lines-per-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue with adding 3 datasets 1 for target values, 1 for lines and 1 for actual values. After adding 3 datasets, first 2 are stacked and only 2nd one is visible with 0.1 value (so it seems like a line). The 3rd dataset is independent (not stacked).